# expand request parameter not working for Events API call

Tags: expand, stripe-payments

I have been using Expand parameter for Charges API call and it was working fine.

But when i used Expand parameter with Events call it gave error.
I wanted to expand `Invoice` ID object.

Following is the URL:

```
https://api.stripe.com/v1/events?type=charge.*&count=100&expand[]=data.invoice'
```

Following is the Error message:

```
[type] => invalid_request_error
[message] => This property cannot be expanded (data.invoice).
```

I also tried to change value like `invoice` , `data.data.invoice` But no success.

How can i get this to work ? Am i missing something ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Event objects can't be expanded, so you'll need to retrieve those invoices individually.

Comment: which ones can be expanded?

Comment: can any get requests be expanded??

Comment: @SleepsOnNewspapers All the properties which can be expanded has an "expandable" label. Reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects